# Informix - Decode a Base-64 encoded string

Tags: base64, informix

I have an attribute in my table which gets converted to a Base-64 encoded string by some .NET code. Now I want to decode the same, but I want to do it in the select query itself.

I am not finding any info (as usual with Informix documentation), but it seems such a thing does not exist. Am I correct?

```
select foranea_ci_persona, ip, BASE64DECODE(query) as Consulta, fecha_hora
  from Historial;
```

The query above does not work at all.

Comment: Do you mean a Base-64 string?  Or a string of 64-bits (8 characters)?  Or something else?  Informix doesn't have built-in Base-64 encode or decode functions AFAIK — at least, not at the SQL level (so there's no BASE64DECODE function as you hope).  It's feasible to write one — either writing it in C and installing it as a UDR (not trivial), or writing it in SPL (stored procedure language), which also not trivial but for a different set of reasons.

Comment: I meant a string encoded in Base64. Sorry for the unclear wording. I see what you mean. I'll have to decode the data in .NET itself then

Comment: Thanks for your answer!